# Limiting includes in Rails for performance issue

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, performance, associations, mariadb

Using Rails 3.2. I am revisiting a [problem I had earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19143398/ruby-geocoder-nearbys-is-slow) which hurts performance while getting nearby shops for a large set of data.

Here is the original code:

```
# statement A
nearby_shops = current_shop.nearbys(10, :order => 'overall_rating DESC')
.where(:shop_type => shop_type).includes(:photos).limit(5)
```

I figured that limiting it to 5 records took **4000+ms** to load (with 300,000 records in the database), but removing the limit took just **20ms**, so my new code is:

```
# statement B
nearby_shops = (current_shop.nearbys(10, :order => 'overall_rating DESC')
.where(:shop_type => shop_type).includes(:photos))[0..4]
```

Statement B checks all records, but with `[0..4]`, it returns 5 records only. I chose not to use `.limit(5)` or `.first(5)` because these 2 functions would still go back to same SQL produced in statement A.

Statement A returns 5 records, and 5 associated photos, the time spent on photos is 10ms;

Statement B returns 100 records, and 100 associated photos, the time spent on photos is 100ms.

How can I limit the `includes` photos to the first five `[0..4]` so that it doesn't include other 95 photos unnecessarily?

Comment: Interesting. What's the SQL produced by both solutions? Which database do you use?

Comment: Also, it would be interesting if you could run [`.explain`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#running-explain) on the queries.

Comment: Damn, I just did few more tests, it was the `:order => 'overall_rating DESC'` that slows things up. If I left it blank, which is `distance ASC` by default, then it's fast.

Comment: `overall_rating` is already indexed.